# Find first position of values in list

Tags: python

If I have a list of 1's and 2's, how can I find the first index of 1 and 2.

For example `[1,1,1]` should output `(0,-1)`, where -1 represents not in the list and `[1,2,1]` should output `(0,1)`, `[1,1,1,2]` should output `(0,3)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way would be to create a separate list for items to look `index`  for and use `index` function and using `list comprehension` (*also additional check is made to make sure item is in list else* `ValueError` *will occur*):

```
my_list = [1,1,1]
items = [1,2]
print ([my_list.index(item) if item in my_list  else -1 for item in items])
```

Output:

```
[0, -1]
```

If tuple is needed then the above list can be converted into tuple using `tuple` function:

```
tuple([my_list.index(item) if item in my_list else -1 for item in items])
```

In longer way without using `list comprehension`:

```
my_list = [1,1,1]
items = [1,2]
# create empty list to store indices
indices = []

# iterate over each element of items to check index for
for item in items:
    # if item is in list get index and add to indices list
    if item in my_list:
        item_index = my_list.index(item)
        indices.append(item_index)
    # else item is not present in list then -1 
    else:
        indices.append(-1)

print(indices)
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Minor quibble. It looked like he wanted a tuple instead of a list. So he should use `tuple([my_list.index(item) if item in my_list  else -1 for item in items])` instead of  just `[my_list.index(item) if item in my_list  else -1 for item in items]`.

Comment: @Christian Dean thanks! for the comment, I will add an update.

Comment: Why would you make this a list comprehension?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I do not have any specific reason for it, I just thought about writing one liner, what would be your suggestion?